# Jquery Scroll shows error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`Stop()` is not working in my html page it shows an error like `this.stop` is not a function"?
Also `Start()` is not working?

My code is

```
<marquee direction="up" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
Here we go</marquee>
```

How to resolve this issue.Please help us.

Comment: Which browser? Be aware, using marquee is like driving a lada

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n54Pc/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using jQuery? If so, please, try to use `$(this).stop();` and `$(this).start();`

Comment: This is not relative to jQuery

Comment: While the tag included Jquery, this is not specifically a jquery question. Sorry, this answer is not correct

Comment: @Netzach, it does not matter, as the code that the OP is using is not jquery specific, so telling the OP to use jquery will only confuse the situation and it will still not work, additionally the OPs code is already correct and using $(this) would be completely un necessary. This answer is still wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry for this. I thought that `stop()` and `start()` functions referred to the corresponding functions in jQuery related to animations.